# Paste multiple elements in R

Tags: r, paste

I make this code using a for-statement. (The main purpose of this code is to list different webpages, which are obtained via httr and rvest)

```
r = "asdgkjkhdf"
t = "osrt"

all = c()
for(i in 1:400)
{
   y   = paste(r, i, sep = '')
   d   = paste(y, t, sep = '')
   all = c(all, d)
}
all
```

I got things like these (pasted numbers are actually getting accumulated in the each results)

```
[1]asdgkjkhdf1osrt
[2]asdgkjkhdf12osrt
[3]asdgkjkhdf123osrt
[4]asdgkjkhdf1234osrt
...
```

But I want results like these regardless of how many numbers i put in 'for()'function.

```
[1]asdgkjkhdf1osrt
[2]asdgkjkhdf2osrt
...
[400]asdgkjkhdf400osrt
```

like these above

What should I change in order to have what I want to result in?
Should I use `paste(substr(), substr(), sep='')`?

Comment: `all <- paste0(r, 1:400, t)`

Comment: I got [1]asdgkjkhdf123441osrt [2]asdgkjkhdf123442osrt ...

Comment: If you really want to use the for-statement: `all = c(); for(i in 1:400) all = c(all, paste0(r, i, t));`. However, the solution without the for-statement that Roland gives is, of course, preferred.

Comment: Oh really appreciate your answer. I got the results i wanted!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a for-statement you can use the following

```
r   = "asdgkjkhdf"
t   = "osrt"
all = c()

for (idx in 1:400) 
   all = c(all, paste0(r, idx, t))
```

However, in R you should prefer code without for-statements since, in general, this is less readable and hurts performance. The solution without the for-statement (given by Roland in the comments) equals

```
all <- paste0(r, 1:400, t)
```

Note that `paste0("string")`is just a short notation for `paste("string", sep='')`.